# How to use Rxjs switchMap to throwError

Tags: javascript, browser, rxjs, rxjs6

I have create a wrapper for fetch function. Based on the code below, test_3 passed but how come test_1 and test_2 hit success callback instead of error callback? I suspect there is something wrong in the way I use throwError.

```
import { from, throwError } from 'rxjs'; // version 6.5.2
import { retry, catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

function getBody(response: Response): Promise<any> {
  const headers = response.headers;

  if (headers.has('content-type')) {
    const contentType: string = headers.get('content-type');
    if (contentType.includes('json')) return response.json();
  }
  return response.text();
}

const http = (url) => 
  from(fetch(new Request(url))
    .pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(error => { // fetch will throw error if page not found.
        console.log('hit catchError')
        return of(new Response(null, { status: 404, statusText: 'Page not found' }));
      }),
      switchMap(async (response: Response) => {
        console.log('response.ok = ', response.ok);
        return response.ok
          ? getBody(response) // all status >= 200 and < 400 
          : throwError({ 
              status: response.status, 
              statusText: response.statusText, 
              body: await getBody(response) 
            });
      }),
    );

// test_1
http('http://this_url_not_exists.com').subscribe(
  response => console.log('should not hit this'),
  errorResponse => console.log('should errorResponse.status = 404'),
);
// test_1 console result:
// hit catchError
// response.ok = false
// should not hit this

// test_2
http('http://this_url_require_authentication.com').subscribe(
  response => console.log('should not hit this'),
  errorResponse => console.log('should errorResponse.status = 401'),
);
// test_2 console result:
// response.ok = false
// should not hit this

// test_3
http('http://myurl.com').subscribe(
  response => console.log('should hit this'),
  errorResponse => console.log('should not hit this'),
);
// test_3 console result:
// response.ok = true
// should hit this
```

Please do not propose me to use rxjs's ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fetch won't throw error for you

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status
>   even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve
>   normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on
>   network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

Update:
Looks like your api call is returning 401 and will be rejected in fetch promise, but you still can't rely on fetch to reject properly. please see the below thread

https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/201

and regarding your code the reason it is not handle by switchMap is you return throwError which is not a promise  ( you mark function with async)

change `throwError(...)` to `throwError().toPromise()` will work properly. but again don't rely on fetch to reject properly

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am not asking whether fetch reject or not. I aldready handle network failure into 404 in catchError. My question is how come throwError in switchMap did not trigger error callback handler in subscribe.

Comment: I am sure, test_1 did trigger catchError

Comment: I have update my question with console result for your reference

Comment: your throwError().toPromise() saved my day. thanks. for the 401 problem you mention, it did not reject promise. If you look at the console result carefully in test_2, it did not hit catchError.

Answer (score 3):

You can return a Promise inside `switchMap` directly.

```ts
switchMap(response => response.ok 
  ? getBody(response) 
  : getBody(response).then(body => {
    throw { status: response.status, statusText: response.statusText, body } 
  }))
)
```

Don't use `async` as in `switchMap(async (response: Response) => { })`!

**The problem** is that `async` causes `switchMap` to return an Observable of whatever you return. So in your `switchMap` if `response.ok == false` you returned an `Observable<Observable<never>>` which then emitted an `Observable<never>` to your success callback.

---

Here are a few general ways to throw an error inside `switchMap`.

**1. Return an Observable that errors.**

```ts
switchMap(response => response.ok 
  ? of(successObject) 
  : throwError(errorObject)
)
```

**2. Throw an error directly**

```ts
switchMap(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return of(successObject)
  } else {
    throw errorObject
  }
})
```

**3. Return a Promise that errors**

```ts
switchMap(response => response.ok
  ? Promise.resolve(successObject)
  : Promise.reject(errorObject)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem is that I need the async in switchMap to get Response.json() content. I already update my question into full source code, is there any way I can use async to solve this problem?

Comment: @Fan Cheung answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to await the Promise inside `switchMap`. You can return a Promise that resolves the body and then throws an error.